# How to call two different webpages when the user clicks submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, html

My code looks likes this:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="uname">
  <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

In register.php file I have a database connection codes.
I need to load another html page after submitting the form simultaneously if the database is connected through the register.php file.

How to do that?

Comment: use header('Location: other_page_url');  after your post request

Comment: check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: You can't call two pages, but you can call the first and this one is redirecting to the second, or you use an ajax request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply redirect the user to the second page once the registration is successful, through means of the **[`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)** function:

index.php:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="uname">
  <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

register.php:

```
// Process registration
if (valid) {
  header('success.php);
}
```

success.php:

```
// Thank the user for registering
```

Alternatively, you could always simply process your `success` page on `register.php` itself.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. It sounds to me like you don't actually need to load 2 URLs simultaneously and what you are looking for is an if statement to execute some code only if post data is set

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
  //code to execute when form is submitted
}
else {
  //code to execute otherwise
}
```

If you do need to make a request to 2 URLs at the same time you are looking for an AJAX request.

More detail in your question about your setup and end goal would be useful to help further.

Answer (score -1):

in your `Register.Php`
add something like this 
check your Sql result something like this

```
$sql='select * Tablename where condition'

$result= fetch($sql)
$row=fetch_array($result)asdsad
if($row>0){
header(Location:'connected.php') // whatever your html
}
else {header(Location:"failed.php")//whenever query got no row
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is efficient as you would be able to browse to failed.php or connected.php in the browser directly without the use of cookies to validate.

Comment: wow @WillCraig are you really willing to judge me? tnx appreciate

Comment: No I just think there are better answers which I have up voted

Comment: Yes you will mr will